# Start a Private Bitcoin Network

Tags: network

Is there anyway to create my own Bitcoin Network?

I'd love to put my first block into self-own Bitcoin Network and make it grow : )

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to play around or test your apps then bitcoin-core's `regtest` mode might be what you're looking for.

Developer examples on `regtest` mode: https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-examples#regtest-mode

A tutorial to get you started: https://geraldkaszuba.com/creating-your-own-experimental-bitcoin-network/

If you want to fork bitcoin and create your own altcoin this guide can be useful: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=225690.0

Answer (score 2):

Starting a private network can be useful for experimenting with new protocol features (such as [the one started by Jeremy Rubin](https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/bitcoin-dev/2022-February/019925.html) for testing [CTV](https://bitcoinops.org/en/topics/op_checktemplateverify/)) or applications (we used one for testing Revault for instance). It is also useful to test the software "as a blackbox": Bitcoin Core has [a comprehensive test suite](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/master/test/functional#functional-tests) that does precisely that.

As mentioned by @user11221 you can use [the `regtest` network](https://developer.bitcoin.org/examples/testing.html#regtest-mode). It is tailored for the Bitcoin Core functional tests and well suited for starting a private network locally. For instance if you want to tinker with Bitcoin Core's internals and see what breaks it's a good choice.

Another, newer, solution is crafting a custom [Signet network](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Signet). This approach is preferable if you want a non-local private network, with a behaviour closer to the main network.