# Setup a private bitcoin network

Tags: bitcoind, network

This question is similar to previosuly asked question [Start a Private Bitcoin Network](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/36341/start-a-private-bitcoin-network) but since I can't comment there I am asking again.

I am working on a concept specifically for existing bitcoin so the suggested methods of `litecoin` or `regtest` are not applicable for my purpose. I need to simulate a bitcoin network over my LAN/Wifi and it would be great if someone could point me towards a method to do it.

Comment: Why won't your own regtest work?

Comment: it can simulate only one node on a machine locally, right ?

Comment: Actually, no, you can use multiple machines on a regtest network, you just have to manually connect them using `addnode`. See [the docs](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#addnode).

Comment: @StephenM347 thanks that works perfectly. However, I have another concern, since `DNS seeding` and `Fixed seeds` are disabled in `regtest` mode, how can I simulate at least one of them so as to simulate a complete bitcoin network with peer discovery on my network ?

Comment: I've added a more modern answer to https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/36341/101498, i think it answers your question here too (TL;DR use Signet) and it can be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Start a Private Bitcoin Network](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/36341/start-a-private-bitcoin-network)